# Wifi Repeated Disconnect & Reconnect Issue

Tags: networking, arch-linux, wifi

Only recently there has been an issue for me where on Arch my Wifi works for a few minutes, and then disconnects for 1 or 2 minutes. After that it connects back and then disconnects after a few minutes. The cycle goes on...

This used to be a problem but for some reason it has grown to be even worse and I have not made many changes network wise. Everything works perfectly fine when on Windows.

`journalctl -f` [output](https://pastebin.com/M4LEwj5i):

```
Jan 03 12:01:20 khosraw-archcraft-hp systemd[1]: reflector.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 69.
Jan 03 12:01:20 khosraw-archcraft-hp systemd[1]: Stopped Refresh Pacman mirrorlist with Reflector..
Jan 03 12:01:20 khosraw-archcraft-hp audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=reflector comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jan 03 12:01:20 khosraw-archcraft-hp audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=reflector comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jan 03 12:01:32 khosraw-archcraft-hp reflector[5600]: error: failed to retrieve mirrorstatus data: TimeoutError: The read operation timed out
Jan 03 12:01:32 khosraw-archcraft-hp systemd[1]: reflector.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 03 12:01:32 khosraw-archcraft-hp systemd[1]: reflector.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 03 12:01:32 khosraw-archcraft-hp systemd[1]: Failed to start Refresh Pacman mirrorlist with Reflector..
Jan 03 12:01:32 khosraw-archcraft-hp audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=reflector comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
Jan 03 12:01:32 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1641232892.358:501): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=reflector comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
Jan 03 12:01:40 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
Jan 03 12:01:41 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
Jan 03 12:01:42 khosraw-archcraft-hp systemd[1]: reflector.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 70.
Jan 03 12:01:42 khosraw-archcraft-hp systemd[1]: Stopped Refresh Pacman mirrorlist with Reflector..
Jan 03 12:01:42 khosraw-archcraft-hp audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=reflector comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jan 03 12:01:42 khosraw-archcraft-hp audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=reflector comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jan 03 12:01:42 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1641232902.607:503): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=reflector comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jan 03 12:01:42 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1641232902.607:504): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=reflector comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jan 03 12:01:42 khosraw-archcraft-hp audit: BPF prog-id=99 op=LOAD
Jan 03 12:01:42 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: audit: type=1334 audit(1641232902.608:505): prog-id=99 op=LOAD
Jan 03 12:01:42 khosraw-archcraft-hp systemd[1]: Starting Refresh Pacman mirrorlist with Reflector....
Jan 03 12:01:42 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
Jan 03 12:01:43 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
Jan 03 12:01:44 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
Jan 03 12:01:44 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
Jan 03 12:01:44 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
Jan 03 12:01:44 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: timed out to flush queue 1
Jan 03 12:02:43 khosraw-archcraft-hp systemd[1]: reflector.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 73.
Jan 03 12:02:50 khosraw-archcraft-hp wpa_supplicant[416]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
Jan 03 12:02:50 khosraw-archcraft-hp wpa_supplicant[416]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
Jan 03 12:02:50 khosraw-archcraft-hp wpa_supplicant[416]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
Jan 03 12:02:50 khosraw-archcraft-hp wpa_supplicant[416]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
Jan 03 12:02:50 khosraw-archcraft-hp wpa_supplicant[416]: nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
Jan 03 12:02:50 khosraw-archcraft-hp wpa_supplicant[416]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with b4:2a:0e:8f:51:14 (SSID='TC8715D0D-5G' freq=5220 MHz)
Jan 03 12:02:50 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: wlan0: authenticate with b4:2a:0e:8f:51:14
Jan 03 12:02:51 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: wlan0: send auth to b4:2a:0e:8f:51:14 (try 1/3)
Jan 03 12:02:51 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232971.1684] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jan 03 12:02:51 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to get tx report from firmware
Jan 03 12:02:52 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: wlan0: send auth to b4:2a:0e:8f:51:14 (try 2/3)
Jan 03 12:02:52 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to get tx report from firmware
Jan 03 12:02:53 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: wlan0: send auth to b4:2a:0e:8f:51:14 (try 3/3)
Jan 03 12:02:53 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to get tx report from firmware
Jan 03 12:02:54 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: wlan0: authentication with b4:2a:0e:8f:51:14 timed out
Jan 03 12:02:54 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232974.2235] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Jan 03 12:02:55 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232975.1634] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jan 03 12:02:58 khosraw-archcraft-hp wpa_supplicant[416]: nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
Jan 03 12:02:58 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: wlan0: authenticate with b4:2a:0e:8f:51:14
Jan 03 12:02:58 khosraw-archcraft-hp wpa_supplicant[416]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with b4:2a:0e:8f:51:14 (SSID='TC8715D0D-5G' freq=5220 MHz)
Jan 03 12:02:59 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: wlan0: send auth to b4:2a:0e:8f:51:14 (try 1/3)
Jan 03 12:02:59 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232979.2198] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jan 03 12:02:59 khosraw-archcraft-hp systemd[1]: reflector.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 74.
Jan 03 12:02:59 khosraw-archcraft-hp audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=reflector comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jan 03 12:02:59 khosraw-archcraft-hp audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=reflector comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jan 03 12:02:59 khosraw-archcraft-hp systemd[1]: Stopped Refresh Pacman mirrorlist with Reflector..
Jan 03 12:02:59 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1641232979.607:523): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=reflector comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jan 03 12:02:59 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1641232979.607:524): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=reflector comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jan 03 12:02:59 khosraw-archcraft-hp audit: BPF prog-id=103 op=LOAD
Jan 03 12:02:59 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: audit: type=1334 audit(1641232979.608:525): prog-id=103 op=LOAD
Jan 03 12:02:59 khosraw-archcraft-hp systemd[1]: Starting Refresh Pacman mirrorlist with Reflector....
Jan 03 12:02:59 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to get tx report from firmware
Jan 03 12:02:59 khosraw-archcraft-hp reflector[5696]: error: failed to retrieve mirrorstatus data: URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution>
Jan 03 12:02:59 khosraw-archcraft-hp systemd[1]: reflector.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 03 12:02:59 khosraw-archcraft-hp systemd[1]: reflector.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 03 12:02:59 khosraw-archcraft-hp systemd[1]: Failed to start Refresh Pacman mirrorlist with Reflector..
Jan 03 12:02:59 khosraw-archcraft-hp audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=reflector comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
Jan 03 12:02:59 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1641232979.747:526): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=reflector comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
Jan 03 12:02:59 khosraw-archcraft-hp audit: BPF prog-id=0 op=UNLOAD
Jan 03 12:02:59 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: audit: type=1334 audit(1641232979.753:527): prog-id=0 op=UNLOAD
Jan 03 12:03:00 khosraw-archcraft-hp wpa_supplicant[416]: wlan0: Trying to associate with b4:2a:0e:8f:51:14 (SSID='TC8715D0D-5G' freq=5220 MHz)
Jan 03 12:03:00 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: wlan0: send auth to b4:2a:0e:8f:51:14 (try 2/3)
Jan 03 12:03:00 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: wlan0: authenticated
Jan 03 12:03:00 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: wlan0: associate with b4:2a:0e:8f:51:14 (try 1/3)
Jan 03 12:03:00 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232980.2265] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jan 03 12:03:00 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: wlan0: RX AssocResp from b4:2a:0e:8f:51:14 (capab=0x1011 status=30 aid=0)
Jan 03 12:03:00 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: wlan0: b4:2a:0e:8f:51:14 rejected association temporarily; comeback duration 672203520 TU (1141637 ms)
Jan 03 12:03:00 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: failed to get tx report from firmware
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <warn>  [1641232981.4036] device (wlan0): link timed out.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232981.4042] device (wlan0): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'supplicant-timeout', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232981.4044] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: stop vif 90:0f:0c:40:f3:3f on port 0
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp avahi-daemon[386]: Interface wlan0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp avahi-daemon[386]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address 2603:8081:160e:2500:8004:8dde:663:2eb1.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: start vif 16:14:d7:d5:69:65 on port 0
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp avahi-daemon[386]: Interface wlan0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp avahi-daemon[386]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.17.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp avahi-daemon[386]: Withdrawing address record for 2603:8081:160e:2500::5 on wlan0.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp avahi-daemon[386]: Withdrawing address record for 2603:8081:160e:2500:8004:8dde:663:2eb1 on wlan0.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp avahi-daemon[386]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.0.17 on wlan0.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp avahi-daemon[386]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.17.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp avahi-daemon[386]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp avahi-daemon[386]: Registering new address record for 192.168.0.17 on wlan0.IPv4.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp avahi-daemon[386]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::b54b:6183:b21a:4e8c.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp avahi-daemon[386]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp avahi-daemon[386]: Registering new address record for fe80::b54b:6183:b21a:4e8c on wlan0.*.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp avahi-daemon[386]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::b54b:6183:b21a:4e8c.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp avahi-daemon[386]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address 2603:8081:160e:2500:8004:8dde:663:2eb1.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp avahi-daemon[386]: Registering new address record for 2603:8081:160e:2500:8004:8dde:663:2eb1 on wlan0.*.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp avahi-daemon[386]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::b54b:6183:b21a:4e8c on wlan0.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp avahi-daemon[386]: Registering new address record for 2603:8081:160e:2500::5 on wlan0.*.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <warn>  [1641232981.8617] device (wlan0): Activation: failed for connection 'TC8715D0D-5G'
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232981.8637] device (wlan0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp avahi-daemon[386]: Withdrawing address record for 2603:8081:160e:2500::5 on wlan0.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp avahi-daemon[386]: Withdrawing address record for 2603:8081:160e:2500:8004:8dde:663:2eb1 on wlan0.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp avahi-daemon[386]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address 2603:8081:160e:2500:8004:8dde:663:2eb1.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp avahi-daemon[386]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::b54b:6183:b21a:4e8c.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp avahi-daemon[386]: Registering new address record for fe80::b54b:6183:b21a:4e8c on wlan0.*.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp avahi-daemon[386]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::b54b:6183:b21a:4e8c on wlan0.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp avahi-daemon[386]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::b54b:6183:b21a:4e8c.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp avahi-daemon[386]: Interface wlan0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp dbus-daemon[388]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.5' (uid=0 pid=390 comm="/usr/bin/NetworkManager --no-daemon ")
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp systemd-resolved[378]: wlan0: Bus client reset search domain list.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp systemd-resolved[378]: wlan0: Bus client set DNS server list to: 2001:1998:f00:1::1, 2001:1998:f00:2::1
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp systemd-resolved[378]: wlan0: Bus client set default route setting: no
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp systemd-resolved[378]: wlan0: Bus client reset DNS server list.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232981.8692] dhcp4 (wlan0): canceled DHCP transaction
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232981.8692] dhcp4 (wlan0): state changed bound -> terminated
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232981.8695] dhcp6 (wlan0): canceled DHCP transaction
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232981.8695] dhcp6 (wlan0): state changed bound -> terminated
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp avahi-daemon[386]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.0.17 on wlan0.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp avahi-daemon[386]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.17.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp avahi-daemon[386]: Interface wlan0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp dbus-daemon[388]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1641232981.875:528): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp systemd-resolved[378]: Switching to fallback DNS server 1.1.1.1#cloudflare-dns.com.
Jan 03 12:03:01 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232981.8975] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
Jan 03 12:03:03 khosraw-archcraft-hp wpa_supplicant[416]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
Jan 03 12:03:05 khosraw-archcraft-hp wpa_supplicant[416]: nl80211: send_and_recv->nl_recvmsgs failed: -33
Jan 03 12:03:05 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232985.9290] policy: auto-activating connection 'TC8715D0D-5G' (c4dce970-afd4-412f-a64f-fa2474d7ae91)
Jan 03 12:03:05 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232985.9297] device (wlan0): Activation: starting connection 'TC8715D0D-5G' (c4dce970-afd4-412f-a64f-fa2474d7ae91)
Jan 03 12:03:05 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232985.9297] device (wlan0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 03 12:03:05 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232985.9299] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jan 03 12:03:05 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: stop vif 16:14:d7:d5:69:65 on port 0
Jan 03 12:03:06 khosraw-archcraft-hp kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:02:00.0: start vif 90:0f:0c:40:f3:3f on port 0
Jan 03 12:03:06 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232986.3814] device (wlan0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 03 12:03:06 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232986.3817] device (wlan0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'TC8715D0D-5G' has security, but secrets are required.
Jan 03 12:03:06 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232986.3817] device (wlan0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 03 12:03:06 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232986.3818] sup-iface[f04492b707e8cadb,2,wlan0]: wps: type pbc start...
Jan 03 12:03:06 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232986.3857] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> interface_disabled
Jan 03 12:03:06 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232986.3861] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: interface_disabled -> inactive
Jan 03 12:03:06 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232986.3874] device (wlan0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 03 12:03:06 khosraw-archcraft-hp wpa_supplicant[416]: wlan0: WPS-PBC-ACTIVE
Jan 03 12:03:06 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232986.3879] device (wlan0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 03 12:03:06 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232986.3881] device (wlan0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'TC8715D0D-5G' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jan 03 12:03:06 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232986.3882] Config: added 'ssid' value 'TC8715D0D-5G'
Jan 03 12:03:06 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232986.3892] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jan 03 12:03:06 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232986.3893] Config: added 'freq_list' value '5035 5040 5045 5055 5060 5080 5170 5180 5190 5200 5210 5220 5230 5240 5250 5260 5280 5290 5300 5320 5500 5520 5540 5560 5580 5600 5620 5640 5660 5680 5700 5745 5760 5765 5785 5800 5805 5825 4915 4920 4925 4935 4945 4960 4980'
Jan 03 12:03:06 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232986.3893] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Jan 03 12:03:06 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232986.3893] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'
Jan 03 12:03:06 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232986.3893] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Jan 03 12:03:06 khosraw-archcraft-hp NetworkManager[390]: <info>  [1641232986.8352] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
```

I tried disabling some services but they didn't seem to do anything so I re-enabled them. Any idea what the issue might be?